# Loading .obj file with multiple objects in one vertex and index buffers

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have working .obj load method that reads all geometry info and append it to vertex and index buffers in one go.

However, my 3D models are more complex than simple cube and contains several objects that I need to interact with somehow. Reading lines with object name tags is not a problem, but I don't understand how to correctly organize this process with **QGLBuffers**. Can I store different objects data in one buffer?

Is it better to add loop with creating new objects directly in load method or somehow reload method in **initializeGL()** every time it reach new 'o' tag?

Should I create new class that will inherit default object class with load method to store different objects or it's possible to store everything in one class.(I've read several articles and examples about inheritance, but didn't had much practice with it and not quite understand what should i do in this situation)?

I've tried to find examples of loading multiple objects in **OpenGL**, looked through code of **Assimp library**, but I didn't found anything related to object names tag, neither storing objects data in single vertex and index buffers.

My SceneObject class

```
class SceneObject
{
public:
SceneObject();
typedef struct {
    QVector3D vertex;
    QVector3D normal;
    QVector2D texcoord;
} Point;

typedef unsigned int PointIdxType;
const GLuint GLPointIdxType = GL_UNSIGNED_INT;

typedef unsigned int FaceIdxType;

QVector<QVector3D> vertices;
QVector<QVector3D> face_normal;
QVector<QVector2D> texcoords;
QVector<Point> points;
QHash<QString,PointIdxType> string_to_point_index;
QVector<PointIdxType> faces_points_indices;
QVector<QVector<FaceIdxType> > point_faces;

QList<SceneObject *> objects;

QGLBuffer vertex_buffer;
QGLBuffer *index_buffer;

void loadObjModel(QString path);
};
```

Using SceneObject in **initializeGL()**

```
curObj = new SceneObject;

if (curObj->vertex_buffer.create())
{
    curObj->vertex_buffer.bind();
    curObj->vertex_buffer.setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    curObj->vertex_buffer.release();
}
else qDebug() << "Couldn't create vertex_buffer";

curObj->index_buffer = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::IndexBuffer);
if (curObj->index_buffer&&(curObj->index_buffer->create()))
{
    curObj->index_buffer->bind();
    curObj->index_buffer->setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    curObj->index_buffer->release();
}
else qDebug() << "Couldn't create index_buffer";

curObj->loadObjModel("model.obj");
```

Using SceneObject in **painGL()**

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

curObj->vertex_buffer.bind();
curObj->index_buffer->bind();
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(SceneObject::Point),0);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,sizeof(SceneObject::Point),(void*)12);
glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(SceneObject::Point),(void*)24);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,curObj->faces_points_indices.count(),curObj->GLPointIdxType,0);
curObj->index_buffer->release();
curObj->vertex_buffer.release();

glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

**loadObjModel** code

```
vertices.clear();
texcoords.clear();
string_to_point_index.clear();
points.clear();
point_faces.clear();
face_normal.clear();
faces_points_indices.clear();

***
reading obj file and appending data
***

vertex_buffer.bind();
vertex_buffer.allocate(points.constData(),points.count()*sizeof(Point));
vertex_buffer.release();

index_buffer->bind();
index_buffer->allocate(faces_points_indices.constData(),faces_points_indices.count()*sizeof(PointIdxType));
index_buffer->release();

obj_file.close();
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's difficult to know what *could* be changed.

Comment: Sorry for that, code added